# GitLab CI: Issue with SAST IaC uploading artifacts - permission denied

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have an error when using the template for IaC SAST.
Gitlab is 14.10, installed in my cloud, and accessible from the internet (I changed my real GitLab ULR to `owngitlab.com`)
The GitLab runner is installed in k8s.

Try to use SAST in my projects, but I get errors. Could somebody please help with this?

Here is part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
include:
  - template: Security/SAST-IaC.latest.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - test
```

Pipeline log:

```
$ /analyzer run
[INFO] [kics] [2022-05-20T12:41:44Z] ▶ GitLab kics analyzer v1.5.2
[INFO] [kics] [2022-05-20T12:41:44Z] ▶ Detecting project
[INFO] [kics] [2022-05-20T12:41:44Z] ▶ Found relevant files in project, analyzing entire repository
[INFO] [kics] [2022-05-20T12:41:44Z] ▶ Running analyzer
[INFO] [kics] [2022-05-20T12:41:44Z] ▶ path /builds/tf/modules
[INFO] [kics] [2022-05-20T12:42:43Z] ▶ Creating report
[WARN] [kics] [2022-05-20T12:42:43Z] ▶ Could not detect git executable
Uploading artifacts for successful job
Uploading artifacts...
gl-sast-report.json: found 1 matching files and directories 
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "sast" to coordinator... error  error=couldn't execute POST against https://owngitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/139/artifacts?artifact_format=raw&artifact_type=sast: Post "https://owngitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/139/artifacts?artifact_format=raw&artifact_type=sast": open gl-sast-report.json: permission denied id=139 token=hZ5dXhA7
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "sast" to coordinator... error  error=couldn't execute POST against https://owngitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/139/artifacts?artifact_format=raw&artifact_type=sast: Post "https://owngitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/139/artifacts?artifact_format=raw&artifact_type=sast": open gl-sast-report.json: permission denied id=139 token=hZ5dXhA7
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "sast" to coordinator... error  error=couldn't execute POST against https://owngitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/139/artifacts?artifact_format=raw&artifact_type=sast: Post "https://owngitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/139/artifacts?artifact_format=raw&artifact_type=sast": open gl-sast-report.json: permission denied id=139 token=hZ5dXhA7
FATAL: invalid argument                            
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: Currently running into the same issue. Have you been able to resolve it somehow?

Comment: @TryToSolveItSimple unfortunately not yet, still got an error